# Developing on WordPress with Hack/HHVM

Tags: wordpress, hhvm, hacklang

I'm running WordPress on HHVM and I'd like to develop themes, plugins and templates with Hack and XHP, rather than PHP. I have noted, that while `<?php /* Template Name: Hack/HHVM test */ ?>` (in a file with a `.php` extension) can be used to create a new page-template, `<?hh /* Template Name: Hack/HHVM test */ ?>` (in a file with a `.hack`) isn't even recognized. Is WordPress development currently lacking support for Hack? What information can be provided on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .hhconfig file wasn't present, and that's what was blocking me. Otherwise WordPress has support for developing with Hack. I have a plugin implementation running now.

Note: The file extension can be either `.php` or `.hh` **but not** `.hack` ([documentation](https://hhvm.com/blog/2019/02/11/hhvm-4.0.0.html#hack-file-extension)), and the file opens with `<?hh`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `<?hh` file with `.php` extension?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. When I do that the plugin displays on the plugin page, but it cannot be activated without a server error.